# How to hide system generated error message while adding duplicate data into MySQL DB using Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, oracle11g

I have created a table with 2 composite keys in MySQL. I am now trying to insert duplicate values and so I'm getting a system generated error message. I want to hide that error message and display my own error message - how can I do that? I have tried using "warn" but the system generated message is still being displayed.

```
$sts = $dbh->prepare("insert into Enrolled(Student_Id,CourseID,DOJ) values(@StudentID,$CourseID,CURDATE())");
$sts->execute() or warn ("Error");
```

output:

> DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '16-11' for key
>   'PRIMARY' at Stud ent.pm line 182,  line 10.Error

Comment: Please show us the code where you set up your database connection. Most likely you have `PrintError => 1` there. Remove that.

Comment: Also, you should add `use strict;` to your code to let Perl tell you about problems in your code. `"insert ... values(@StudentID,..."` will not do what you want, because either you have no `@StudentID` array or you're doing very weird code... Seeing that you have other variables there, maybe you _have_ an array `@StudentID`. Still, you should use DBI placeholders https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values

Answer (score 1):

You can set `PrintError => 0` attribute when you connect to database. By default it is on.
Also you can try setting this attribute in `$dbh->prepare`. Should work for that statement handle only according to the documentation https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#PrintError

Comment: No, eval doesn't in any way catch stuff printed to STDERR or warn.

Comment: It needs the `SIG{__WARN__}` hook for stderr (and that may not always work).  But the question for me is, why dismiss warnings/errors? Fix'em so there aren't attempts to enter duplicate data.